# Як перекласти з англійської `moron`?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Я перекладаю аніме, і в даному контексті `moron` звучить не вульгарно і не дуже грубо. Я думав перекласти це як "придурок" але трохи не звучить, які пропозиції?

Comment: [«Пришеле́п(к)уватий»](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=moron&dicts=all)?

Comment: @Sasha думаю це те що я шукав, дякую.

Comment: @Sasha напишіть відповідь, я відзначу як правильну.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я пропоную **«пришеле́п(к)уватий»**.

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

> **[ПРИШЕЛЕ́ПУВАТИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryshelepuvatyj)**, а, е, *фам[ільярне]*. Нетямущий, безтолковий. *— Йди геть ік твоєму дурному батькові, що пустив на світ таку пришелепувату дочку!* (Борис Грінченко, II, 1963, 263); *— Слухайте, може, я пришелепуватий, але я вас ще не зрозумів* (Юрій Смолич, V, 1959, 224).
>
> ---
>
> **[ПРИШЕЛЕ́ПКУВАТИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryshelepkuvatyj)**, а, е, *фам[ільярне]*. Те саме, що **пришелепуватий**. *Він ніби пришелепкуватий трохи, а до Насті, бач, залицяється* (Іван Цюпа, Вічний вогонь, 1960, 61).

[«Словники на E2U»](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=moron&dicts=all):

> - Загальний народний англійсько-український словник 2010–…:
>
>   **moron** [ˈmɔːrɒn, *амер.* ˈmɔːrɑːn ˈmoʊr-] *n*
>             *розм[овне]* недоу́мкуватий, пришеле́пуватий, недоу́м, недоу́мко, недоу́мок; ідіо́т
> - Великий англо-український словник 2011 (Є. І. Гороть, Л. М. Коцюк, Л. К. Малімон, А. Б. Павлюк.):
>
>   **moron** [ˈmɔ:rɒn] n недоумкуватий, розумово відсталий.

Квазісиноніми зі [«Словників України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):

> **ДУРНИ́Й** (розумово обмежений), **НЕРОЗУ́МНИЙ**, **ВІДСТА́ЛИЙ**, **НЕДОТЕ́ПНИЙ**, **ТУПИ́Й**, **ТУПОУ́МНИЙ**, **ДУРНОГОЛО́ВИЙ** розм., **ПУСТОГОЛО́ВИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ТВЕРДОГОЛО́ВИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ТУПОГОЛО́ВИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ДУБОГОЛО́ВИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **БЕЗГОЛО́ВИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **БЕЗМО́ЗКИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ДУРНОЛО́БИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ПУСТОЛО́БИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ТВЕРДОЛО́БИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ТУПОЛО́БИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **МІДНОЛО́БИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **НЕСПО́ВНА́ РО́ЗУМУ** *розм[овне]*, **КРУ́ЧЕНИЙ** *зневажл[иве]*, **ТУПОРИ́ЛИЙ** *зневажл[иве]*, **ДУРНОВЕ́РХИЙ** *зневажл[иве]*, **ПРИШЕЛЕ́ПУВАТИЙ** *вульг[арне]*, **ПРИШЕЛЕ́ПКУВАТИЙ** *вульг[арне]*, **ПРИТЕЛЕ́ПКУВАТИЙ** *вульг[арне]*, **МАКОЦВІ́ТНИЙ** *діал[ектне]*; **ДУРНУВА́ТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ПРИДУ́РКУВАТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **НЕДОУ́МКУВАТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ДУБУВА́ТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ТУМАНУВА́ТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **БЛАГУВА́ТИЙ** *розм[овне]*, **ГЛУПУВА́ТИЙ** *розм[овне] рідше* (також — який виражає деяку розумову обмеженість, тупість). <…> — Пор[івняйте] 1. **божеві́льний**, 2. **обме́жений**.

Answer (score 0):

Одна людина розказувала, шо в деяких волинських селах неприйнято було відверто описувати людину як дурня і був поширений евфемізм «немудрий», що означало акурат «дурень». Може, є контексти, в яких не тільки волинські селяни зрозуміють, шо лагідне «немудрий» означає саме «пришелепкуватий».

Comment: Думаю, це непоганий варіант. Ви також можете покращити свою відповідь, зробивши посилання на джерела. До прикладу, Словник української мови в 11 томах (СУМ-11) містить статтю [немудрий](http://sum.in.ua/s/nemudryj) - можна було би процитувати тут перше значення цього слова. Щоб відредагувати свою відповідь, натисність _edit_ під нею.

Comment: Це не є відповіддю на це питання.